Mongoose in serverless - why awaiting connection helps to avoid duplications?
I'm fairly new to serverless development and trying to find the best practice for using mongoose in such environment.
A page in official documentation (Using Mongoose With AWS Lambda) explains the way to do. However, there's a piece of code that makes me confused:
// `await`ing connection after assigning to the `conn` variable
// to avoid multiple function calls creating new connections
await conn.asPromise();

Here, I can't figure out why the sample function may potentially invoke multiple calls and how is awaiting connection helps with it. From what I know:

Mongoose will automatically wait for a connection to be established before executing any query. So it's fine to query without awaiting the connection.
No matter it's serverless or not, the code is running in Node.js, which guarantees single threading with no race condition at all. As soon as conn global variable is assigned, there's no way the subsequent function calls will ever create a new connection. (i.e. pass through if (conn == null) check)

Is there something I got wrong? Please correct me if I did.

The way I read that comment is about Lambda's caching of functions.  By doing all of the connection logic when the conn variable is null, only the first time a container is used will the connection logic fire, as opposed to the reused container connecting to the database each time it's invoked.
